# I am not able to get any output in console using NotificationCenter in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, notificationcenter

I am new to Swift Programing Languge and I'm trying to get a output when the song changes. Code has no any error.

Below is my code

```
import UIKit
```

import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var trackChangedObserver : AnyObject?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    trackChangedObserver = NotificationCenter.default
        .addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                     object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) -> Void in
                        self.updateTrackInformation()
    }

}
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(trackChangedObserver!)
}

 func updateTrackInformation() {
    let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

    let currentTrack: MPMediaItem? = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem
    let title = currentTrack?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
        as? String ?? "None"
    print(title)
    let artist = currentTrack?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist)
        as? String ?? "None"
    print(artist)
    let album = currentTrack?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle)
        as? String ?? "None"
    print(album)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
```

nc.post(name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange, object: nil)

To register to catch a notification being posted, use this:

```
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateTrackInformation()), name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange, object: nil)

    @objc func updateTrackInformation(notification: NSNotification) {
    let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

    let currentTrack: MPMediaItem? = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem
    let title = currentTrack?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
        as? String ?? "None"
    print(title)
    let artist = currentTrack?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist)
        as? String ?? "None"
    print(artist)
    let album = currentTrack?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle)
        as? String ?? "None"
    print(album)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should call this in `viewDidLoad` or earlier, or notifications will not be sent:

```
let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
```

Second issue is related to memory management (retain cycle):

```
trackChangedObserver = NotificationCenter.default
    .addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                 object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] notification  -> Void in
                    self.updateTrackInformation() //!!!!!
}
```

You are capturing here `self` as strong reference. And `NotificationCenter` will keep it forever so your ViewController will never be destroyed and `deinit` method will not be called. To fix add [weak self] to the closure (as I did above).